# Prove that an entire function has at least one complex zero

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, laplace-transform, error-function

Let $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, g(z) = \int_0^\infty{e^{-z t} e^{-t^2} dt}$.

Prove that there is a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z) = 0$.

Note that $g(z) = \frac{e^{z^2/4} \sqrt{\pi}}{2} . erfc(z/2)$ so the zeros of $g$ are the zeros of the $ercf$ function (up to a trivial homothetic transformation).

Note also that $g$ is an entire function and that any zero satisfies $\Re(z)<0$ (a fact I was able to prove).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you know about Hadamard's theory of entire functions of finite [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type)?

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that and it seems very powerful. So, I work by contradiction and assume $g$ don't have zero.  $g$ has a finite order 1/2 and by Hadamard's theory, $g(z) = e^{P(z)}$ with $P$ a polynomial. The leading coefficient of $P$ is necessarily  negative as $g(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$. Then I define $h(z) := \frac{g(z) - g(0)}{z g(z)}$, $h$ is entire and thanks to the Hadamard representation, $h$ is bounded and thus constant. From that I deduce that $g$ is constant and get my contradiction. Does it seems OK to you? Do you see an easier path? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The order of $g$ is $2$, not $1/2$. I suppose that's just a typo, but just in case. I'm not sure how you would conclude that $h$ is bounded from the assumptions. If you can give a correct argument for that, you have a correct proof, otherwise you have a hole. I thought of looking at $g'(z)$ and concluding from that that $g$ cannot have the form $g(z) = e^{P(z)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can estimate

\begin{align}
\lvert g(z)\rvert
&\leqslant \int_0^{\infty} e^{\lvert z\rvert t} e^{-t^2}\,dt \\
&= e^{\lvert z\rvert^2/4} \int_0^{\infty} e^{- (t - \lvert z\rvert/2)^2}\,dt \\
&= e^{\lvert z\rvert^2/4} \int_{\lvert z\rvert/2}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}\,du \\
&< \sqrt{\pi}\cdot e^{\lvert z\rvert^2/2}\,.
\end{align}

Thus $g$ is of order $\leqslant 2$, and since the first inequality is an equality for negative real $z$, the order of $g$ is exactly $2$. (If the order were not an integer, we'd already be done because an entire function of fractional order attains every complex value infinitely often.)

If $h$ is an entire function of finite order without zeros, then $h(z) = e^{P(z)}$ for some polynomial $P$, and consequently $h'(z) = P'(z)\cdot h(z)$. For $g$, we compute - since differentiation under the integral is legitimate -

\begin{align}
g'(z) &= \int_0^{\infty} \biggl(\frac{d}{dz} e^{-zt}\biggr)e^{-t^2}\,dt \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} (-t)e^{-zt}e^{-t^2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-zt}\biggl(\frac{d}{dt}e^{-t^2}\biggr)\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2}e^{-zt}e^{-t^2}\biggr\rvert_0^{\infty} - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \biggl(\frac{d}{dt}e^{-zt}\biggr)e^{-t^2}\,dt \\
&=-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{z}{2} g(z)\,.
\end{align}

If $g$ had no zeros, from this calculation and the above remark it would follow that

$$Q(z)\cdot g(z) \equiv 1$$

for some polynomial $Q$ (namely $Q(z) = z - 2P'(z)$ where $g(z) = e^{P(z)}$) and hence

$$\frac{1}{g(z)} = e^{-P(z)} = Q(z)$$

is a polynomial. But since the left hand side has no zeros it follows that $Q(z) \equiv 1$ and hence that $g$ is constant. From that we can obtain various contradictions. For example

$$0 = g'(0) = \frac{0\cdot g(0)-1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}\,.$$

Looking a bit closer at this argument shows that it proves more than just the existence of one zero, it proves the existence of infinitely many zeros. For if $g$ had only finitely many zeros, then we would have the factorisation

$$g(z) = R(z)\cdot e^{P(z)}$$

with polynomials $R,P$, and hence $g'(z) = (R'(z) + R(z)P'(z))\cdot e^{P(z)} = Q(z)\cdot g(z)$. This contradicts $g'(z) = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{z}{2}g(z)$ by exactly the same argument.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a complete answer. I have learned a lot in complex analysis today :)

Comment: That's great. Means it was time well spent for both of us.